# Multiply 2D tensor with 3D tensor in pytorch

Tags: pytorch, matrix-multiplication

Suppose I have a matrix such as P = [[0,1],[1,0]] and a vector v = [a,b]. If I multiply them I have:

Pv = [b,a]

The matrix P is simply a permutation matrix, which changes the order of each element.

Now suppose that I have the same P, but I have the matrices M1 = [[1,2],[3,4]] and M2=[[5,6],[7,8]]. Now let me combine them as the 3D Tensor T= [[[1,2],[3,4]], [[5,6],[7,8]]] with dimensions (2,2,2) - (C,W,H). Suppose I multiply P by T such that:

PT = [[[5,6],[7,8]], [[1,2],[3,4]]]

Note that now M1 now equals [[5,6],[7,8]] and M2 equals [[1,2],[3,4]] as the values have been permuted across the C dimension in T (C,W,H).

How can I multiply PT (P=2D tensor,T=3D tensor) in pytorch using matmul? The following does not work:

```
torch.matmul(P, T)
```

Answer (score 1):

An alternative solution to [@mlucy](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3200554/mlucy)'s [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69033571/6331369), is to use [`torch.einsum`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.einsum.html). This has the benefit of defining the operation yourself, without worrying about [`torch.matmul`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.matmul.html)'s requirements:

```
>>> torch.einsum('ij,jkl->ikl', P, T)
tensor([[[5, 6],
         [7, 8]],

        [[1, 2],
         [3, 4]]])
```

---

Or with `torch.matmul`:

```
>>> (P @ T.flatten(1)).reshape_as(T)
tensor([[[5, 6],
         [7, 8]],

        [[1, 2],
         [3, 4]]])
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like:

```
torch.matmul(P, X.flatten(1)).reshape(X.shape)
```